# Pandas - Sort dataframe but limit the amount in every page for a specific element in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there's a way to sort a dataframe by a numeric value but keep just X ocurrencies based on another column? For example, let's say I want to use a dataframe as a catalog and paginate him (so every page would have 5 items). And in every 5 items I need to have at max 2 items of the categorical column.

```
product     seller
 10         seller1
 9          seller1
 8          seller2
 7          seller2
 6          seller2
 5          seller3
```

And then I would want something like:

```
product     seller
 10         seller1
 9          seller1
 8          seller2
 7          seller2
 5          seller3
 6          seller2
```

The last 2 lines change place because in the static 1-5 "page1" the seller2 already had 2 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try with `cumcount`

```
out = df.sort_values(by = 'seller', key = lambda x : df.groupby('seller').cumcount()//2)
Out[145]: 
   product   seller
0       10  seller1
1        9  seller1
2        8  seller2
3        7  seller2
5        5  seller3
4        6  seller2
```

Comment: is there a way to use this but keeping it ordered by the column product? imagine if the incidences of seller2 appeared before the ones for the seller1, how would i keep the values from seller1 on top based on their values?

Comment: @yyz_vanvlet you could sort the value first